# String on stack - temp strings in c without cleanup

Tags: c, string, stack, allocation

Is there a better way to temp alloc a string of unknown length in C in a way that doesn't require cleanup?

I currently use the following, which does use alloca/_alloca or insert the name your compiler likes for this function

```
// OLD
// #define stackdup(s)     \
//    memcpy(memset(_alloca(strlen(s) + 1), 0, strlen(s) + 1), s, strlen(s))

#define stackdup(s)     strcpy(_alloca(strlen(s) + 1), s) // refined per comments

// stackndup and stackmiddup can't use strcpy because they need memset 0 ...

#define stackndup(s,n)  \       
    memcpy(memset(_alloca(strlen(s) + 1), 0, strlen(s) + 1), \
        s, n > strlen(s) ? strlen(s) : n ) 
#define stackmiddup(s,pos,n) \
    memcpy(memset(_alloca(strlen(&s[pos]) + 1), 0, strlen(&s[pos]) + 1), \
        &s[pos], n > strlen(&s[pos]) ? strlen(&s[pos])) )

int main ()
{
    const char *address         = "123 Main Street";
    const char *copy_address    = stackdup    (address);       // "123 Main Street"
    const char *address_123     = stackndup   (address, 8);    // "123 Main"
    const char *address_123x    = stackndup   (address, 55);   // "123 Main Street"
    const char *address_main    = stackmiddup (address, 4, 4); // "Main"

    ...
}
```

Takes advantage of how memcpy and memset return the dest, formats the buffer one extra byte to provide for null termination.

Can't use it in a loop obviously as it would allocate on the stack again and again.

Comment: You want to declare it globally only ?

Comment: How about `char address[] = "123 main street";`? Why can't you use that?

Comment: Why do you use memset and memcpy instead of just strcpy ?

Comment: Sounds like an improvement ;-)

Comment: I'd recommend `char address_main[5]; snprintf(address_main, sizeof address_main, "%s", address + 5);` . All these macros may seem cute but it makes your code look weird to a maintenance programmer. You could wrap that in a macro if you really want.

Comment: of course another option is to not do this in the first place, and change whatever function you are calling to take a pointer and a length, instead of expecting null-terminated string

Comment: @Matt - If I can do in 1 line without a structure and the code is clean and obvious, it is inherently better to any implementation that requires fixed buffers (fixed buffers are toxic because you can get surprise string truncation) or requires creating a struct.   

Copying a string is a simple deal -- it shouldn't require a library or a sophisticated struct or really any thought at all.   

Assembly language, which C is supposed to be superior to, could throw a string on the stack easy.

Comment: @B.Nadolson `char buffer[x]` is the same memory layout as `_alloca(x)`

Comment: I was responding to your example where you snprintf into a fixed size buffer using sizeof.  I'm not really in favor of null terminated strings, but most of the time in C that is what will be used.

Comment: Just a warning. If a user has control over the string, it's relatively trivial to overflow your stack and crash or if you're threaded overflow the stack and write to some other memory (potentially other threads stack). Never do alloca on a length that you don't have full control over. Alloca is powerful, but it's also very dangerous in some situations. Compilers have options to do alloca safely, but as far as I know no compiler does that by default.

Answer (score 1):

With a C99 compiler, local arrays can be dynamically sized:

```
  void demo (const char * original)
  {
     char copy[strlen (original) + 1];
     strcpy (copy, original);

     ...
  }
```

This works the same way as `alloca`, but it's cleaner and (more) portable.

Comment: I agree in principal, but Microsoft Visual Studio is C89 and I want it to work with any mainstream compiler.

Comment: _" and (more) portable"_ not quite... C11 made VLA's optional again. C11 compilers may not be able to handle VLA's then, so it's only portable provided you stick to C99 compliant compilers. VLA's would however solve the OP's issue with strings in a loop,as they'd be GC'ed after each termination, and not flood the stack

Answer (score 1):

If the length is unknown and can be big, do not use `alloca` due to stack overflow, use `malloc` & `free` instead, or, to be on-topic, there are some libraries for garbage collection, but by using them, performance might be decreased.

If possible, do not allocate strings again. And if is there needed maximum performance, pass their lengths with them except calling `strlen()`.

For example, instead of

```
const char *address         = "123 Main Street";
const char *copy_address    = stackdup    (address);
```

Use

```
char address[] = "123 Main Street";
char* copy_address = address;
```

In the second case address will be writable, in the first not. By this way, you can make `stackndup` and `stackmiddup` a lot faster - if these strings are used one by one in a row (for example, printing or writing them, or copying to structure with static arrays, like `struct { char street[32]; }`), you can just save index (or better pointer) with original character and write there zero. Note that you will have to make function to recover the original string - set original character back where it was.

**EDIT**
Memory friendly cut & substring functions (for null-terminated strings) doing too same as your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


/*
 Macros
 */
#define plong long


#define istr_init(i) \
    char* __ptr##i = NULL; \
    char prev##i; \

#define istr_cut(i,s,n) \
    (char*) s; \
    if(n > s##_len) { \
        (__ptr##i) = NULL; \
    } else { \
        __ptr##i = (s + n); \
        prev##i = *(__ptr##i); \
        *(__ptr##i) = 0; \
    }

#define istr_substring(i,s,pos,n) \
    (pos > s##_len) ? "" : (char*) ((__ptr##i) = (s + pos)); \
    if(pos > s##_len) { \
        (__ptr##i) = NULL; \
    } else { \
        if((pos + n) < s##_len) { \
            (__ptr##i) += n; \
            (prev##i) = *(__ptr##i); \
            *(__ptr##i) = 0; \
        } else { \
            (__ptr##i) = NULL; \
        } \
    }

#define istr_back(i) \
    if(__ptr##i) { \
        *(__ptr##i) = (prev##i); \
        (__ptr##i) = NULL; \
    }


/*
 Main
 */
;int main() {
    {
        istr_init(1); //Init - our ID=1
        char* cur;
        char address[] = "123 Main Street";
        unsigned plong address_len = strlen(address); //<name>_len required

        cur = istr_cut(1, address, 8);
        printf("   address_123: [%s]\n", cur);
        istr_back(1);

        cur = istr_cut(1, address, 55);
        printf("  address_123x: [%s]\n", cur);
        istr_back(1);

        cur = istr_substring(1, address, 4, 4);
        printf("  address_main: [%s]\n", cur);
        istr_back(1);

        cur = istr_substring(1, address, 4, 55);
        printf(" address_mainx: [%s]\n", cur);
        istr_back(1);

        cur = istr_substring(1, address, 55, 4);
        printf("  address_null: [%s]\n", cur);
        istr_back(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   address_123: [123 Main]
  address_123x: [123 Main Street]
  address_main: [Main]
 address_mainx: [Main Street]
  address_null: []
```

Answer (score 0):

If C++ is not an option and automatic cleanup is the goal, you could try this [library](https://github.com/Snaipe/libcsptr) which provides C++ style smart pointers with automatic memory management (on the heap though).